# How to add java.awt.image package in Android

Tags: android, image, jar

I have an external library that relies on the `java.awt.Image` package.  However, the Android library does not contain it. Does anybody know how to add it to Android? 
Thanks!

Comment: Android has its own image routines (in `android.graphics`) which are somewhat more efficient on hardware with limited resources. Please explain what you want to do with `java.awt.image`, as it may already be available, and you're just not familiar with where it is in the inbuilt libraries.

Comment: Can you post the import code you're using?

Comment: @Mark Allison: I am using ImageJ library, which basically relies on the java.awt.image package. Since Android does not have this package, so I can not use the ImageJ library. The ImageJ library is very powerful and has a lot of image processing operations I need.

Comment: @Thomas Owers: 
import ij.IJ;
import ij.io.Opener;
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.ImageJ;

just import an external library, but it relies on java.awt.image package

Comment: have you not tried import java.awt.Image; ?

Comment: @Thomas Owers: Yes, I have. But you know I can not import it because Android library does not have it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Java AWT classes contain native code, so unless someone ports that native code to Android, you are out of luck. And, they won't port it, because as it was pointed out above, Android has its own graphics libraries (`android.graphics`).

Comment: If so, I guess I can not use the existing image processing library.

Comment: Right, you are not going to be able to use ImageJ. What is it that it does that you need to do in your app? There is a very good chance that there is an existing Android API that covers your use cases.

Comment: @michaelg I need to implement SIFT algorithm in Android. There is an implemented sift in java which is a plugin of ImageJ. That's why I want to use ImageJ. What Android API do you suggest for my app?

Answer (score 4):

Use JavaCV. http://code.google.com/p/javacv/
Its allready precompiled for Android 2.2 : http://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to justify Hitesh answer after seeing up votes (which misleads). If am wrong, please correct me.

Well, I have also been enthusiast in using few core concepts of Java like Swings and AWT libraries in Android.

Recently I wanted to use `java.awt.Color` class because it is much better than  `android.graphics.Color`. So done a small research by reading few threads and concluded as 'No we cannot import'. By seeing Hitesh answer I thought I failed my research and found very easiest solution for my problem. Followed the steps for a sample and run my code. Alas!!!

`NoClassDefFoundError` exception has thrown.

Once again made a small research for concluding Jeffrey (accepted) answer. I found conclusion [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Toolkit.java#Toolkit.loadLibraries%28%29). The comment above the method `loadLibraries()` explains everything. This method has been called in [Color](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Color.java) class (line 279).

Answer (score -4):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33210293/5418475

The AWT package is not supported in Android, you need to change your implementation to use the Android classes.

See these similar questions:

Porting AWT graphics code to Android

How to add java AWT image package in Android

Using AWT with Android

Comment: The proper action is to flag the question as duplicate, or just comment (when you have enough rep), not copy the answer...