# Java classes in Android app

Tags: java, android

I want to use Java classes in my Android project. Is that possible and if it is possible, what do I have to do to use the following classes?

- BufferedImage
- ImageIO
- ImageOutputStream
- FileImageOutputStream
- GifSequenceWriter

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add java.awt.image package in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344654/how-to-add-java-awt-image-package-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

Android doesn't have an implementation of AWT. The closest parallel is [android.graphics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

BufferedImage -> [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html). You can search some 3rd party libraries. I didn't see any substitution.

[From another answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6345814/2350145)

> The Java AWT classes contain native code, so unless someone ports that
>   native code to Android, you are out of luck. And, they won't port it,
>   because as it was pointed out above, Android has its own graphics
>   libraries (android.graphics).