# Accessing Java AWT classes in Android

Tags: java, android, awt, itext, jfreechart

I am trying to export a pdf file containing a plot. I have achieved this in Java using the JFreeChart library and iText, using [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/generate-pie-chart-bar-graph-in-pdf-using-itext-jfreechart/).

Now I am trying to do the same in Android. But since android does not support the awt classes, I am facing issues. Specifically

`java.awt.Graphics2D;
 java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;`

Since the awt classes will not be used for any UI rendering, is it possible to include them some how? Tried adding the jar file, but the classes remain unresolved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499960/how-to-create-pdfs-in-an-android-app

Comment: Creating the pdf is not the problem, exporting the chart is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344654/how-to-add-java-awt-image-package-in-android